# Why might IIS change to a response redirect URL to another value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, web, iis-8

I'm facing with an odd situation and I think IIS is the cause, however since I'm not an expert in it so it is a guessing at this point. I asked our network admin and he did not agree.

In part of my C# code I'm redirecting the user to a new URL:

```
string currentURL = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host;

string url = string.Format("http://" + currentURL + "/AppDir/Page1.aspx?Item={0}&From={1}",
                           employeeNo, "Search");

Response.Redirect(url, true);
```

But, out of nowhere, a folder gets inserted into my URL path, and it is rendered as something like:

> `http://www.example.org/`**`portal`**`/Page1.aspx`

It is funny that there is no a single keyword as *"portal"* in my project, so I end up with a 404 Not Found page.

- What is causing it? Can this be a policy defined in IIS by admin?
- It works fine locally, but it happens when I upload it to a server.

Comment: Looks like AppDir is getting replaced. Are you sure that's the code you're using? What is the value of currentURL?  Do you have any rewrite rules etc?

Comment: have you tried to debug this line? ```string url =```

Comment: Did you check the value of currentURL? Is your app hosted in IIS under a "portal" folder?

Comment: Mason, thanks for your response. I'm using `string currentURL = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host;` and that gives me the host name always

Comment: StfBln, yes I did and watched it in runtime and it is OK.

Comment: not clear if your redirect is just to a different folder on the same website. i assume not, but you probably know that you don't need the full url if that is the case

Comment: O. Gungor, would you please explain more about it? I will appreciate it.

Comment: tym32167, yes I have traced it. it is just two lines and all the variables are showing up properly in debug time. I believe something on the server forcing it.

Answer (score 0):

The admin has admitted that the DNS does it. Not sure, why but it detects it as an invalid URL so it replaces the folder name with a pre-defined name.

Comment: I think this is not a very technical question now after finding the reason. Can/should I remove this thread?